# How do you bind keys to CTRL-r for reverse-i-serach in bash

Tags: bash, search, scripting

I tried the following in my `.bash_profile`

```
bind '"rr":"^R"'
```

to open the `reverse-i-search` prompt when I type `rr` into the bash prompt but this does not seem to work.  Any ideas?

Comment: That worked!  Maybe you could post an answer with this command `bind '"rr":reverse-search-history' and I could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bind '"rr":reverse-search-history'
```

Should make it. The second part of a `keyseq:function-name` binding must be a readline function name, not another keyseq. To know more about the readline functions, just `man bash` and go the the `READLINE` section.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the concept of a readline function.  Could you explain it a bit more in your answer as well maybe?  Because `reverse-search-history` does not seem to be an executable utility in bash (which is expected since it only modifies the behavior or bash rather than do something different).

But I do not think I know of other functions like this.  Maybe they exist and are helpful?

Comment: Would you know how I can search back when I am in `reverse-search-history` mode?  `rr` doesn't seem to work then

Answer (score 1):

Binding the `rr` keys to the `reverse-search-history` command seemed to work like so

```
bind '"rr":reverse-search-history'
```